# Proof of symmetric difference with empty set (Basics of discrete mathematics).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am a newbie in learning discrete mathematics. I know that $A\Delta\{\}=A$ and $A\Delta A=\{\},$ but i don't understend why, and how can i prove it.

I tried to use basic definition of symmetric difference and got this:

$$A \Delta \{\}= (A \setminus \{\})\cup(\{\} \setminus A).$$

I can't find any information about proving those two statements, and about $A \setminus \{\}$ and $\{\} \setminus A$.

Is it correct and how does it work if yes?

Comment: Another way to look at it: $A \Delta \{\}= (A \cup\{\}) \setminus (\{\} \cap A).$

Answer (score 2):

I presume you know that X- Y= {x| x in X and x not in Y}.  In particular $X- \phi= X$ and $\phi- X= \phi$ since the empty set does not have any members.

Comment: As this answer suggests, you should read $A\setminus \{\}$ as "all the elements of $A$ that are not in $\{\}$." Of course nothing is in $\{\}$, so this is the same as "all the elements of $A$", hence $A\setminus \{\} = A$. Likewise, you should read $\{\} \setminus A$ as "all the elements of $\{\}$ that are not in $A$." Hopefully it's clear why nothing matches this condition....